# How to transfer list into str and expand each word to a row in SparkSQL?

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I need to use `StringIndexer` of Spark MLLib to rank the frequence of words, but it needs format like

```
df = spark.createDataFrame(
[(0, "a"), (1, "b"), (2, "c"), (3, "a"), (4, "a"), (5, "c")],
["id", "category"])
```

but what I have now is like

```
df = spark.createDataFrame(
[(0, ['a', 'b']), (1, ['b', 'c']), (2, ['c','g']), (3, ['a','b']), (4, ['a','b']), (5, ['c','a'])],
["id", "category"])
```

Therefore, I need to transfer the list of each row to words and then expand one row to two rows so that each row includes one word.
Then, I need to give the rank that we get from `StringIndexer` back to my original row, for example, if 'a' ranks 1 and 'b' ranks 3, then add a new column `1,3` for the first row.
How can I do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure if this is the exact output you are looking for, but here's an approach using `explode()` and `collect_list()`:

```
from  pyspark.sql.functions import explode, collect_list
from pyspark.ml.feature import StringIndexer

df_exploded = df.select("id", explode("category").alias("category"))
indexer = StringIndexer(inputCol="category", outputCol="categoryIndex")
indexed = indexer.fit(df_exploded).transform(df_exploded)

indexed.groupBy("id")\
  .agg(collect_list("category").alias("category"),
       collect_list("categoryIndex").alias("categoryIndex")) \
  .sort(asc("id")) \
  .show()
+---+--------+-------------+
| id|category|categoryIndex|
+---+--------+-------------+
|  0|  [a, b]|   [0.0, 1.0]|
|  1|  [b, c]|   [1.0, 2.0]|
|  2|  [c, g]|   [2.0, 3.0]|
|  3|  [a, b]|   [0.0, 1.0]|
|  4|  [a, b]|   [0.0, 1.0]|
|  5|  [c, a]|   [2.0, 0.0]|
+---+--------+-------------+
```